# Spring Unit testing rest controller error

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test

This is my UserController, get() method which returns all UserDto's.

```
@GetMapping("/")
public List<UserDto> get() {
    return userService.getUsers().stream().map((User user) -> toUserDto(user)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And, [this](https://pastebin.com/6TtGF1Kc) is my UserControllerTest testing this get() method which fails. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm making first steps with testing.

This is the console log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at pl.rmitula.restfullshop.controller.UserControllerTest.getAll(UserControllerTest.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:389)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:110)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:83)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:62)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: youe need to mock your userService

Comment: @pvpkiran Could you show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

You are not mocking the required service.

You need a mock of `userService` to be injected into your controller, and mocked response if required.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class UserControllerTest {

@Mock
private UserService userService;


@InjectMocks
private UserController userController;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
void setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(this.userController).build();
}

@Test
void getAll() throws Exception {
    List<UserDto> userdtos = Arrays.asList(
            new UserDto((long) 1, "John", "Snow", "johnsnow@blackbastard.com", "snow", "password"),
            new UserDto((long) 2, "Tyrion", "Lanister", "tyrion@lannister.com", "tyrion", "password"));

    String url = "/api/users";
    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(get(url)).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).andReturn();

    Assert.assertEquals("failure", mvcResult.getResponse(), userdtos);

}
```

}

I'm not a big fan of the standalone approach and find the `WebMvcTest` slice test cleaner which effectively does the setup for you.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
    class UserControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;


    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

//tests
}
```

Comment: Ok, but both of this examples still don't work for me. I got same [NullPointerException](https://pastebin.com/snZ2BBGH) with [this code](https://pastebin.com/PBd6tzLQ) . Could you check this?

Comment: add your full controller too

Comment: and are you actually mocking some sort of collection, even if empty, to return for the stream? Null will be the default.